# What Exactly math.Exp does?

Tags: go

Sorry, but I am not able to understand what exactly `math.Exp` is doing in following code block:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    for x := 0; x < 8; x++ {
        fmt.Printf("x = %f ex = %8.3f\n", float64(x), math.Exp(float64(x)))
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
x = 0.000000 ex =    1.000
x = 1.000000 ex =    2.718
x = 2.000000 ex =    7.389
x = 3.000000 ex =   20.086
x = 4.000000 ex =   54.598
x = 5.000000 ex =  148.413
x = 6.000000 ex =  403.429
x = 7.000000 ex = 1096.633
```

And, I am not able to understand what exactly is `math.Exp` function is doing internally and converting `float64(x)` to respective values as in the output. I have read the `go`'s [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Exp), which says as below:

> Exp returns e**x, the base-e exponential of x.

Reading which I am not very clear of the purpose and mechanism of `math.Exp` function.

I am actually interested in what binary/mathematical operation is going under the hood.

Comment: Don't you know `e^x`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: No, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the value of `e^x` (also expressed as `e**x` or simply `exp(x)`).

That function is based on the number `e=2.71828...` [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), which is defined (among other definitions) as:

```
Lim (1+1/n)^n when n tends to infinity
```

Particularly, the [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) `e^x` has many properties that make it special, but the "most" important is the fact that the function itself is equal to its [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), i.e.:

`Let f(x)=e^x, then f'(x)=e^x`

This translates to the fact that the value of the [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) in one point is equal to the value of the function in that point.